# Removing first key of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array from my database like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [A] => Array
                (
                    [0] => A
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [C] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C
                    [1] => 6.9167
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [D] => Array
                (
                    [0] => D
                    [1] => 6.9167
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

How can I remove the first key `( [0] => A, [0] => C, [0] => D )` from this multidimensional array?

This is my desired output of the array:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [A] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0
                        [1] => 0
                        [2] => 0
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [C] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 6.9167
                        [1] => 0
                        [2] => 0
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [D] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 6.9167
                        [1] => 0
                        [2] => 0
                    )

            )

    )
```

Comment: uncelar what the desired output is

Comment: you said the data is from a db, just don't select it to start with

Comment: for some reason i have to select it that way

Comment: What is the logic? Before `C` has three elements and after three again. While other subarrays have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At it's simplest (I don't have time for a non loop one):

```
foreach($array as $k1 => $inner) {
   foreach($inner as $k2 => $value) {
       unset($array[$k1][$k2][0]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is terrible but should work for you. It uses the level 2 key as a value of the element to delete on the next level

```
$array = array(
    array('A' => array('A', 100, 200)),
    array('B' => array('B', 100, 200)),
);

foreach($array as $key => $subarray){
    foreach($subarray as $letter_key => $target_array){
        $index_to_delete = array_search($letter_key, $target_array);
        unset($array[$key][$letter_key][$index_to_delete]);
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `unset`

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'A' => array(
            'A', 0, 0, 0
        )
    ),
    array(
        'C' => array(
            'C', 0, 0, 0
        )
    )
);


foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $erase = key($value);
    unset($array[$key][$erase][0]);
    // this resets the ordinal sequence from 1,2,3 to 0,1,2
    $a[$key][$erase] = array_values($array[$key][$erase]);
}
```